# Kendo UI MVC Grid theme change

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

Is it possible to apply a particular theme in one Kendo UI MVC component?
I have a Grid that I would like to customize with a different theme.

Something similar to the jQuery version

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    theme: "[theme]"
    ...
});
```

Here is what I have:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<xxxxx.Models.CountrySelectionModel>()
        .Name("countrySelectionGrid")            
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.DepartureCountry);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ArrivalCountry);
            columns.ForeignKey(c => c.TargetCountryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ValidCountryDataSource)
                   .EditorTemplateName("CountrySelectionEditorTemplate")
                   .ClientTemplate("#: TargetCountry #");
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(180);
        })

        .ColumnMenu()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable(pager => pager
            .PageSizes(true)                
        )

        .Navigatable()
        .Selectable(selectable =>
        {
            selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
            selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
        })
        .Sortable(sortable =>
        {
            sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
        })
        .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
        .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

            .Ajax()
            .Model(model => {
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
                model.Field(p => p.DepartureCountry).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.ArrivalCountry).Editable(false);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("Getxxx", "xxx", new { companyId = ViewBag.CompanyId }))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Updatexxx", "xxx", new { companyId = ViewBag.CompanyId }))
            )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible out of the box, due to the way that kendo uses a base CSS file, overriding parts of that with a single themed CSS file of your choice. This very question was discussed on the [kendo forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/setting-a-theme-on-individual-controls) where a possible solution is set out by the Telerik team. They cite the following reasons for not supporting this out of the box:

> 1. Although the implementation is easy, it will cause a considerable increase in the CSS files' size and complexity.
> 2. Using multiple themes on a single page is rare. Most developers will not benefit from this feature, but on the contrary.

It might be possible to work around this by hosting your grid in an `iframe` or `frameset` where you can keep the CSS imports entirely seperate (please note, I haven't tried this approach!). Depending on your scenario of course, this might introduce even more complication due to a need to comunicate between the frames. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the theme reference above of each views separately not the layout and reference which one you like in each views. Not recommended but i think its a way